# Create image montage without resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a folder of images and I want my website to display them all without resizing them while minimizing whitespace. 

 Is this possible at all?

 A few of the images would be able to be rotated to make it fit better, but I'm not sure how I would go about this. The page would have to figure out the way to arrange the images correctly to minimize whitespace, and then create divs with absolute page positions to place each image at that location. 

 I would also want the page to be able to dynamically resize, so a layout algorithm that takes a few seconds to run would make window resizes super slow. 

 I found some tutorials on how to do this WITH resizing, but I'm trying to keep the relative sizes of each image the same to one another, so I can't resize them.

Comment: Can you show us what do you achieve so far? `I found some tutorials` Can you give us more details about them?

Comment: What I have now is basically what they have here: http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/. They use a plugin but I coded it myself - it adjusts the heights and widths of the images so that they nicely line up in rows. But the issue is I can't adjust the sizes. I'm making a product page with stuff like pencils and erasers, and with this method the eraser could end up being resized to be twice the size of a pencil. My client wants shoppers to know the sizes of the items relative to each other by just looking at the pics, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle (http://jsbin.com/) with your code and the problem? It will be very easier to me to help you like this. Please update the question with any new point (like your comment above) so other people could understand the full picture.